# Calling PHP file on button click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two different buttons in my page.  clicking on the first one  must call a  php file named derive_rules.php while cliking on the second one must call another file named derive_rules1.php using ajax. For same i tried following code. But it is not working,

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".deriver").click(function() {

            var val = $("#keyword").val();
            var agent = $(this).attr('rel');
            if(val == '') {$("#keyword").focus(); return;}
            else {

                $.ajax ({

                    url: 'derive_rules.php', 
                    data: 'kw='+val+'&agent='+agent, 
                    type: 'GET', 
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    cache: 'false', 
                    success: function(data) {

                        if(data.success == 'true') {

                            $("#results_holder").show();
                            $("#results").html(data.msg);
                            $("#keyword").val('');

                        }

                        else {

                            alert(data.msg);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

and those are mu buttons

```
<td><b>+ New Rule</b></td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "Keyword" id = "keyword" style = "width:300px" placeholder = "Keyword or Phrase"/></td>
            <td><input type = "button" value = "Verify" class = "Buttons deriver" rel = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/></td>
            <td><input type = "button" value = "Add" class = "Buttons deriver" rel = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/></td>

        </tr></table>
```

what changes should i apply on my code to make it work???? as i want

Comment: Can you please format your code and provide a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: second button dont have class deriver1, both button have same class , so  $(".deriver") would trigreed on both buttons

Comment: I really thank you but  I changed them the first one stayed like the original name and the second one changed to deriver1 and still not working :?

Comment: @user3577813 : Dude, I'm sure my code will work fine. You can see [Latest Update](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/3m2Mt/). In my FIDDLE. If is not working correctly. Try to add `alert box` for `button class`. Tell us is it working or not

Comment: Im sorry you all did your best and your code is working very well but it seems that there is something wrong thats why my code is not working .. i did every thing told to me but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the quick solution.

**HTML**

```
<button class="same" data="derive_rules">Button One</button>
<br/>
<button class="same" data="derive_rules1">Button Two</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".same").click(function(){
   var url = $(this).attr("data");
   //alert(url);
   $.ajax ({
      url: url+".php",//pass the url here or you can use whatever I used .php. And do the other stuff etc.
   });
});
```

For more go to my [JSFILLDE](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/3m2Mt/)

If you need my help. Please find me any of social network by searching `yeshansachithak`.

**Here Is Your Code - As You Want - For more explain**

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><b>+ New Rule</b></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="Keyword" id="keyword" style="width:300px" placeholder = "Keyword or Phrase"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" data="your_file_name" value="Verify" class="Buttons deriver" rel="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" data="your_file_name" value="Add" class="Buttons deriver" rel="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Just pass another attribute in your `<button data="your_file_name" .....`. Then use your ajax call as like you did. Your button class is `driver`. Please see below.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".deriver").click(function() {
        //Edit by Yesh
        var url = $(this).attr("data");
        //To check
        alert(url);

            var val = $("#keyword").val();
            var agent = $(this).attr('rel');
            if(val == '') {$("#keyword").focus(); return;}
            else {

                $.ajax ({

                    //url: 'derive_rules.php', //Edit by Yesh
                    url: url+'.php',//You can use whatever extension (.html ect..)
                    data: 'kw='+val+'&agent='+agent, 
                    type: 'GET', 
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    cache: 'false', 
                    success: function(data) {

                        if(data.success == 'true') {

                            $("#results_holder").show();
                            $("#results").html(data.msg);
                            $("#keyword").val('');

                        }

                        else {

                            alert(data.msg);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Thanks dude.
If you need my help. Please find me any of social network by searching `yeshansachithak`.

Comment: I tried but the second button is not responding :'(

Comment: any other help please can you recheck  it for me please Im not very good in ajax and jquerey

Comment: Did you check my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/3m2Mt/)?. Just try it again. Clearly I did it in to your code also.

Comment: I did check it and I applied everything just like you mentioned earlier and still not working :?

Comment: @user3577813 Please again go to my [UPDATED JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/3m2Mt/). then try it. If you need any help please contact me through any social network by seraching `yeshansachithak`. Thanks

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 
  $(".deriver").click(function() {
   var url = $(this).attr("data");
   alert(url+".php);
   var val = $("#keyword").val();
   var agent = $(this).attr('rel');
   if(val == '') {$("#keyword").focus(); return;}
   else {
   
    $.ajax ({
    url: url+".php"
     //url: 'derive_rules.php', 
    thats the changes.. anything wrong

Comment: and this is the buttons code changes>>>>>><td><b>+ New Rule</b></td>
   <td><input type = "text" name = "Keyword" id = "keyword" style = "width:300px" placeholder = "Keyword or Phrase"/></td>
   <td><input type = "button" value = "Verify" class = "Buttons deriver" data = "derive_rules" rel = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/></td>
   <td><input type = "button" value = "Add"  class = "Buttons deriver" data = "derive_rules1" rel = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/></td>

Comment: @user3577813 Lot of syntax was there. Remove spaces make it simple and clear. `id = ""`. you use like that. Remove in everywhere. No spaces required for html. After that just check your `jquery code`. In you paste code in comments. `" " and ; { ) are missing. so syntax errors will never give you the result. [JUST GO AND TAKE THAT JSFIDDLE CODE. IT"S WORKING PROPERLY](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/3m2Mt/).

Comment: @user3577813 `finally, It worked properly , many many thanks :) –  user3577813` So, Why don't you mark my answer as a correct answer. Please mark it and vote it up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

look at classes on button , need to change selector

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".deriver0").click(function() {

            var val = $("#keyword").val();
            var agent = $(this).attr('rel');
            if(val == '') {$("#keyword").focus(); return;}
            else {
                $.ajax ({
                    url: 'derive_rules.php', 
                    data: {kw:val,agent:agent},
                    type: 'GET', 
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    cache: 'false', 
                    success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                });
            }
        });
        $(".deriver1").click(function() {
            var val = $("#keyword").val();
            var agent = $(this).attr('rel');
            if(val == '') {$("#keyword").focus(); return;}
            else {
                $.ajax ({
                    url: 'derive_rules1.php', 
                    data: {kw:val,agent:agent},
                    type: 'GET', 
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    cache: 'false', 
                    success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<td><b>+ New Rule</b></td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "Keyword" id = "keyword" style = "width:300px" placeholder = "Keyword or Phrase"/></td>
            <td><input type = "button" value = "Verify" class = "Buttons deriver deriver0" rel = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/></td>
            <td><input type = "button" value = "Add" class = "Buttons deriver deriver1" rel = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/></td>

        </tr></table>
```

Comment: I tried but the second button is not responding :"(

Comment: any other help please can you recheck it for me please Im not very good in ajax and jquerey